# AWS SNS not working on live ec2 server using PHP AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I have used SNS service to send SMS on mobile. I have used PHP AWS SDK to server this purpose.

I have tested script in our local server and it sends sms on mobile successfully but when i upload the script in ec2 server then it does not work.

Script hang the web page and sending sms does not work. It does not give any error and loads the page until it get timeout.

We have used http://xxxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ AWS ec2 instance.

My php script is as follows:

```
require 'vendor/aws-sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\S3\SnsClient;

$params = array(
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                        'secret' => AWS_SECRET_KEY,
                    ),
                    'region' => 'us-east-1',
                    'version' => 'latest'
                );

                $sns = new \Aws\Sns\SnsClient($params);

                $result = $sns->publish([
                    'Message' => "Message here", // REQUIRED
                    "SMSType" => "Transactional",
                    'PhoneNumber' => "xxxx", // phone number with country code
                    'MessageStructure' => 'SMS'
                ]);
```

Please suggest.

what we are doing wrong?

Is it any server configuration required to send SMS? or

Do we need to create another ec2 instance with different AWS Region?

Comment: Show us your code. How can we know what are you doing wrong without your code?

Comment: @Justinas i have added the script in question please review and suggest

Comment: Make sure that your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` are defined correctly.

Comment: AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY are defined correctly because it is working correctly on my local server

Comment: And on remote server? Literally `var_dump(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY); die();` at the beginning of your code and make sure it matches local server

Comment: Yes, I have checked in server AWS_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SECRET_KEY is same as local server.

Comment: print the return value of $sns->publish and see what is wrong